# SharedPreference access in a service does not return the value

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I am using a Preference Fragment. In my tests on the device its possible to edit and change the value of the edit textfield and after reopening the settings, the value is correctly changed. But when I access the preference in my service, the value has not changed.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Here is my PreferenceFragment

```
    public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener{

    private static final String TAG = SettingsFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
```

There Activity which shows the fragment

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends Activity {

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();


}       
}
```

My preferences xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <PreferenceCategory 
           android:title="@string/pref_sendall_address_title"
       >
                   <EditTextPreference
                    android:key="@string/pref_sendall"
                    android:title="@string/titleSendallAddress"
                    android:summary="@string/summarySendall"
                    android:dialogTitle="@string/editSendallAddress" 
                    android:defaultValue="http://192.168.101.202/test"                      
                    />
       </PreferenceCategory>
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

In my service i access the sharedpreference like this

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    final String sendallUrl = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_sendall),"n/a");
    Log.d(TAG, "using sendall address " + sendallUrl);
```

Comment: What is `R.string.pref_sendall`?  Why aren't you using the key `pref_test`?

Comment: you can check you preference file /data/data/you_app_package/shared_prefs , and confirmed that whether preference string you are looking is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the resource name in second line

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
final String sendallUrl = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_test),"n/a");
Log.d(TAG, "using sendall address " + sendallUrl);
```

Comment: I posted accidently an old version of my preferences.xml. This is not the reason. The name is correctly, its definded as pref_sendall also I try to access it with this name in my service

Comment: try another default value instead n/a as this is an xml file ,may be it makes a problem

Comment: i tried it, but this does not solve it. Any other idea?